# Disable auto-login from the CLI

Tags: command-line, gdm, gui, login-screen

After successfully installing Ubuntu and logging in to the Unity desktop, I followed the prompts to enable the proprietary display drivers.

After rebooting, the Unity desktop is now entirely unresponsive. The mouse pointer moves but I can't do anything.

After some research, it looks like it is specifically a problem with these drivers and Unity, so I should be OK with, say, the classic Gnome desktop.

Unfortunately, I enabled auto login so I don't get the chance to chose another desktop. Can I fix this from the CLI?

Comment: More up to date: http://askubuntu.com/questions/106428/how-to-disable-automatic-login

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create or modify the file `/etc/gdm/custom.conf`, and write the following content:

```
[daemon]
TimedLoginEnable=false
AutomaticLoginEnable=false
TimedLogin=enzotib
AutomaticLogin=enzotib
TimedLoginDelay=30
DefaultSession=gnome
```

where `enzotib` should be replaced with your username and `gnome` could be replaced by

- `gnome` - for Ubuntu
- `gnome-classic` - for Ubuntu classic
- `gnome-2d` - for Ubuntu classic (no
  effects)