# How to disable autologin if the desktop is not functioning?

Tags: lightdm, auto-login

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to disable automatic login?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/106428/how-to-disable-automatic-login)

I have tried to login to a desktop that is not fully functioning.

I want to get back to Ubuntu - I can do this if I could boot to the user login screen - how can I force this at boot?

Thanks.

Comment: No, not a duplicate!!  I don't want to disable automatic login - quite the reverse!!