# How to disable autologin in Lubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu, auto-login

I like to switch sometimes between Lubuntu and Ubuntu 2D on my laptop. But I especially like to choose which one I will use in the session I am about to start. But the only way of choosing is start the laptop up, and the last used thing will show up (as it should), then log out completely, and choose the other thing from the login menu.

I have spent a lot of my lifetime using Windows, and always I was asked a login BEFORE I actually could do anything. Now I think it is weird that anyone can log into a password-protected account without giving any passwords, as long as the last user was the Admin. Also: will logging out before shutdown help?

Here is my [**default.conf**](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1176520/) file.

Comment: Can you paste the contents of `default.conf` to http://paste.ubuntu.com instead of taking a screenshot? Be sure to give a link.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this.  To disable autologin, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below.

```
sudo leafpad /etc/lxdm/default.conf
```

In the fist few line, you will see something like `autologin=username` change it to the original state of
`# autologin=dgod`.  Save the file, and then reboot your machine.

Also try to go to System Settings --> Users and Groups, click on change next to Password

[image]

Make sure that the box is unchecked next to *Don't ask for password on login*
[image]

Try to edit `sudo leafpad /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` with these contents:

Remove or comment out the following lines

```
autologin-user=username
autologin-user-timeout=0
```

For 14.04 everything works.  The `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` doesn't exist in 14.04, but the other ways work.  See image below:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Tried it 3 times (Lubuntu: old hardware => massive startup time) and no difference at all. The file saved correctly as it is still changed to what you said.
Maybe there is another setting that still has to be adjusted?

Comment: Can you include the output of your `default.conf` file?

Comment: these are the first lines of it: @Mitch [base]
## uncomment and set autologin username to enable autologin
# autologin=dgod

## uncomment and set timeout to enable timeout autologin,
## the value should >=5
# timeout=10

## default session or desktop used when no systemwide config
session=/usr/bin/startlubuntu

## uncomment and set to set numlock on your keyboard
# numlock=0

Comment: I don't know how to do the grey box thing nor how to start new lines without sending the comment in... I'm really sorry.

Comment: No need to be sorry.  What Lubuntu release are you running?

Comment: sysinfo tells me it is called: Ubuntu 12.04 (Precise) Does that mean that it isn't Lubuntu?

Comment: Lububtu is based on Ubuntu.  Give me some time, I'll install Lubuntu, and get back to you.

Comment: umm.. sorry for the interruption, but Mitch, can you move this to chat please? May be someone from AUGR can also jump in to assist, if required.  @nathan: We tend to keep comments minimal and have discussions in chat. You can now talk in chat. [click here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room)

Comment: For an update: The question was solved in chat, and the answer now contains updated solution.

Comment: This answer needs updating. As is, it seems to pile up solutions without varifying which ones actually work and in which versions of Lubuntu. I can attest that the GUI version does not work in 14.04, editing `/etc/lxdm/default.conf` doesn't work too, and `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` doesn't even exist.

Comment: @mikewhatever See added info in my answer.

Comment: Needs updating. None of the edited files exist. 

Use Adriaan's solution below instead.

Answer (score 5):

Ubuntu / Lubuntu 20.10:

First edit

```
vi /etc/sddm.conf
```

It looks like this:

```
[Autologin]
User=<your_user>
Session=Lubuntu
```

I assume you can just comment out the entries:

```
[Autologin]
#User=<your_user>
#Session=Lubuntu
```

Adapt and reboot

Comment: This works for me, and I changed with `Session=LXDE`, which is what I prefer.

Answer (score 2):

So I am using a Lubuntu 14.04.1 LTS installed on a USB stick. And this is how I managed to disable auto loging for Live Session User.

1. Create e new user (to use for loging): **System Tools -> Users and Groups**
2. Open console: **System Tools -> XTerm**
3. enter command:

   ```
   sudo leafpad /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
   ```

   the text editor should apear
4. replace line:

   ```
   autologin-user=lubuntu
   ```

   with

   ```
   autologin-user=name_of_user_you_created
   ```

   optional you could change line

   ```
   autologin-user-timeout=0
   ```

   to

   ```
   autologin-user-timeout=60"
   ```
5. **save and close file**
6. **reboot**

for more info access: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LightDM

After power up you should see the login screen with the user you created waiting for password.

Atention: user "lubuntu" is still there but is not presented in the dropdown list.
if you want to access it you need to chose other then insert user name by hand.
Also leave blank for password as user lubuntu does not have a password by deault.