# Add a login screen on boot to Lubuntu 14.04

Tags: lubuntu

So, I've been using Lubuntu for about three months now, and recently gor around to adding new users. What I was wondering is if there's any way to add a login splash screen (like the Windows login screens) on boot, so you have to select a user or guest to proceed. How do you do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable autologin in Lubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/q/182274/22949) or [How to disable automatic login?](http://askubuntu.com/q/106428/22949)

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can.

Open Users in preferences, and click your user account. (You will need to unlock it). 
Somewhere there, you will see a `Login at boot` or `Login automatically` options.

Uncheck that box.

Answer (score 0):

If Tim's answer errors out, here is a link to [LXDM](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/lxdm), the default login manager for LXDE