# How to Make Ubuntu User Default

Tags: login-screen

I am switching from Lubuntu to Ubuntu Unity. However, unless I specifically set at login Ubuntu as my environment I get LXE without any taskbar -- I purged Lubuntu desktop. How do I set Ubuntu Unity as my default environment for a user?

Comment: Try to [disable autologin](http://askubuntu.com/questions/182274/how-to-disable-autologin-in-lubuntu) for Lubuntu.

Comment: Try: http://askubuntu.com/questions/371742/how-to-restore-ubuntu-login-screen-after-lubuntu-install?rq=1