# How to ENABLE password for administrator account so I am prompted when I log in?

Tags: password, restore, administrator

I am new with Ubuntu, and though I am liking it a lot I am making the typical mistakes (for what I have seen on the forum :-))

I took off the password for the admin account, not knowing that this would cost me being on the computer for a few hours figuring out how to put it back on (done).

However, I am no longer prompted to enter the password when I first log into the system, which I want to amend.

Does anyone know how to amend this from the Terminal?

Thanks to all 
Alex

Comment: Your problem is not very clear. What do you mean by administrator account: <your initial account> - can gain admin privileges in Ubuntu or root? have a look at this thread http://askubuntu.com/questions/106428/how-to-disable-automatic-login

Comment: Hi, I mean the initial account. I made the mistake of removing the password as I found it inconvenient. Then realized I shouldn't have and fixed it through the root in Terminal. The password is enabled now, but when I start my computer I am no longer asked to enter a password. (I want to be requested the password again).... thanks a lot!

Comment: @Alex The link Pavel posted ([this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/106428/how-to-disable-automatic-login)) should still fix this problem. Have you tried that?

Comment: @ Eliah,

Thanks for the post.

I have tried some of the things on that link.. but as you can see there are many people offering advise and there are multiple advises given.

My main concern is to do something on the system and have to reinstall it because of a mistake I might make without noticing it.

Is any particular advise better? I appreciate the time!

Alex

Comment: Alex, two things 1) this type of configuration is not going to mess up your system (unless you forget all your passwords) 2) if ever something else messes up your system, a reinstall is not the end of the world. You should just keep track of what you install for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

**From the Command Line**

To **activate the login-screen** from the command line do the following:

> sudo nano /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf

Then paste or type this line in the file:

> greeter-show-manual-login=true

This should allow you to use the login screen.

Be ware though, what you call admin user, is actually called root user in non-windows terminology.

[Source](http://handytutorial.com/login-as-root-ubuntu-12-04-12-10/)

**With GUI**

To do this without commandline: hit user in the HUB, then switch on [image]auto-login.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the info. But I guess I am not explaining myself well... I dont want to log in as root, I am sure I dont want to have the possibility to screw my computer  ;) However, I would like to be asked for the password of my account when I log in (my account being the one with administrator privileges when I first installed Ubuntu). Right now, I start my PC and I can log into the system without entering any password... even if later the keyring asks me for the password I am able to do multiple things on the computer without entering it. (my User says I should be asked for password).

Comment: does the GUI way help you?