# ubuntu 13.10 - not prompted for login at start up

Tags: 13.10, login, security, unity-greeter

Mostly - oddly not every time - when I reboot, or start up my laptop, I am not prompted for a password; it goes straight into my desktop. I don't like this one bit. There are other users on my laptop, I'd rather get a greeter that allowed the booting to select their user. I am the only admin user. Sometimes, when I do get a greeter (for just my user), after I login, I get kicked out and have to login again. Again, this is not consistent behaviour.

I can't be certain, but this may have began shortly after I bought an external monitor. Certainly the double login stuff started at that time. It happens now, on occasion, whne I am not plugged into the external monitor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you share /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf ? (or /etc/gdm/custom.conf)

that link: [How to disable automatic login in LightDM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/106428/how-to-disable-automatic-login) might help