# How can I return to the login screen when xbmc is always booting?

Tags: login, screen

I am new to Ubuntu. And since I updated to Ubuntu 15.04 I enabled the auto login for my username and it should start with xbmc. I also checked the box for reconnect. My problem now is that I can not get back to the login screen where I can choose between what session to start (kde, xbmc, kubuntu desktop...).

How can I get back to kde desktop and change the reconnect setting so that in the future when I log out of xbmc I get to the login screen. Right now I choose to leave xbmc and it turns dark.  After a couple of seconds I am back in xbmc.

Hope to get some help.

Regards,
K.

Comment: What happens when you hit ``\`` in `xbmc`?

Comment: We can [disable autologin](http://askubuntu.com/questions/106428/how-to-disable-automatic-login) from a TTY accessed by pressing CTRL+ALT+F1 - login as a user with admin permissions.

Comment: I tried \ in xbmc and the xbmc window got small and was located in the upper left corner.

Comment: I tried editing the lightdm.conf and saved it. I changed the session from xbmc to Ubuntu, # the auto logins. But after I restarted it went straight to xbmc screen. Is there no way to switch to the kde desktop?

Answer (score 0):

You may try pressing Ctrl-Alt-F1 on your keyboard and should see a terminal login window.

Enter a normal user and password to login

After that try to become user root via `sudo bash` and entering the password again (the user must be allowed as an administrative user)

If everything is working, you are on shell with just the "#"-sign - that means you are root

Try to stop and restart the lightdm daemon

first

`service lightdm stop`

after a few seconds

`service lightdm start`

I am not sure per 100% but I thing that this time there will be no autologin.

---

Update:

Remove / Rename the lightdm conf and restart

1.

proceed as above

BUT INSTEAD `service lightdm start` follow up with:

2.

`cd /etc/lightdm`

3.

`mv lightdm.conf lightdm.conf.bak`

4. `restart`

After that auto-login should be disabled

Comment: Hi Tom, I tried but after putting in the line with the start service I got a line: job for lightdm.service failed...

Comment: You are user root ? Try the command `whoami` please once

Comment: You also may try `sudo service lightdm start`

Comment: When I put in whoami it tells me I am root.

Comment: I tied your suggestion but it did not work either.

Comment: You are using the standard Ubuntu distro 15.04 and Unity Desktop I guess? What you also can try inside the text terminal (as user root) is: see answer part2

Comment: Hi tom. It did not work. I still get the same error after typing "lightdm restart": job for lightdm.service failed. See "systemctl status light.service" and "journalctl-xe" for detail.

Comment: Hi Klarow, what was happen after restart of the system? Was the autologin still active? Please check your display manager by entering on console: `cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager`.