# Ubuntu not asking for password to log in

Tags: 14.04, login, password, lock-screen

I am trying to lock my system, but it seems like though it is locking but  it is not asking for password to login.

Even when I changed setting from **Settings > User Account** and rebooted my system the password is by-passed.

I tried everything, but don't know which setting is causing this problem. If anyone can help with this?

Comment: Run this command in terminal: `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen` . What does it tell you ?

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy Tells me false. What should I do next? The given answers are not helping me.

Comment: @Nikhil If it says `false` , then this setting is alright, so not the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I found my answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/106428/how-to-disable-automatic-login-in-lightdm). Since these questions have different phrases I thought of not deleting my question. This might help somebody else.

Run `sudo grep nopasswd /etc/*`

This will display at least 2 lines:

```
/etc/group:nopasswdlogin:x:112:`<login name>`   
/etc/gshadow:nopasswdlogin:!::`<login name>`
```

Edit those files with `sudo` and remove only  from those lines and save.

Restart the computer and now it should ask for the password again!

Answer (score 1):

Run the following command from your terminal:

```
sudo gpasswd -d $USER nopasswdlogin
```

It should solve your problem.