# Disable auto login so I can choose desktop environment

Tags: gnome

I've installed gnome-session-fallback on my ubuntu GNOME 14.04 beta, after that i logged out and logged in selecting Gnome Classic (Compiz) but some how it is screw up... and the only thing i see is the wallpaper and nothing more. To quit i have to force shutdown by pressing button of my laptop.

Now, i want to select the default desktop environment of ubuntu gnome, but i can't access to login screen because i have autologin option active...
What should i do?

I have tried recovery mode and:

```
sudo apt-get --purge gnome-session-fallback
```

but it gives me an error..

Comment: What kind of error? This might be relevant: http://askubuntu.com/questions/44107/disable-auto-login-from-the-cli

Comment: hi @jmunsch after reboot, it logs in into ubuntu using last Desktop enviroment and the it does not gives me any error message. It only shows wallpaper, no panels, no mouse pointer no nothing.. only the wallpaper. tks for the link i will try that.

Comment: This too may be relevant: http://askubuntu.com/questions/311773/accidentally-deleted-gnome-session-login-no-longer-works

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to jmunsch help it's solved.

After booting press Ctrl+Alt+F1 this should get you to tty

then edit the custom.conf file

```
sudo nano /etc/gdm/custom.conf
```

disable AutomaticLoginEnable

Answer (score 3):

Goto

> System Settings>User Accounts

Look at the right side press unlock and enter your password
and then turn off automatic login