# How can I switch to Unity/Ubuntu mode from xbmc kodi?

Tags: session, xbmc, kodi

I selected the xbmc default mode via switch user. Now my computer directs me to xbmc. I want to switch to my default Ubuntu 14.04 desktop. I tried to exit, but it starts again in xbmc.

Comment: Try this:

http://askubuntu.com/questions/442386/disable-auto-login-so-i-can-choose-desktop-environment

Possible duplicated topic.

Answer (score 0):

I turn on the guest mode and then switch to default mode. However the other solution did not work.

sudo nano /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf