# AutoLogin does not turn off

Tags: 16.04, login, password, system-settings, privacy

Ubuntu has been on my Laptop for almost half a year now. I used to have a login password, then turned it off about two months ago. After reading this (http://www.faz.net/aktuell/wirtschaft/netzwirtschaft/einreise-am-flughafen-was-tun-wenn-der-grenzschutz-ans-handy-will-14881037.html) article (about people being prompted to unlock devices at airports) i decided to go back to a password in order to be able to protect my data.

Navigating to the system settings, unlocking the user account with the sudo password and changing the automatic login flag to 'off' and setting a password i though i would be prompted for a password again upon startup. This is NOT the case, ubuntu keeps loggin me in withoug a password.

Trying to solve the problem by myself i found these two articles: [Disable auto-login from the CLI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/44107/disable-auto-login-from-the-cli) and [How to disable automatic login in LightDM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/106428/how-to-disable-automatic-login-in-lightdm) . I followed directions of both, no change.

What am i doing wrong? Am i missing something? Why is the system doing this? It is worrying me :S

**Summary: Ubuntu 16.04 does not go back to prompting a password upon login after having been set to autologin about two months ago.**

Any help or hint would be very much appreciated.

All the best from Germany, 
Hardovic

Comment: If it can boot without requiring your password, that means your home folder isn't encrypted, so border officials can just make an image of your hard drive and use that. You'll want to encrypt your home folder.

Comment: Thank you for you quick reply. I'll have to look into that!

Comment: You may be confusing *autologin* with *paswordless login* - see for example [No password asked at login screen just start session button with LightDM](http://askubuntu.com/questions/100010/no-password-asked-at-login-screen-just-start-session-button-with-lightdm/102222#102222)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved thanks to user [steeldriver](https://askubuntu.com/users/178692/steeldriver).

My username was in the passwordless login list. It was removed by running the terminal command in this article:

[No password asked at login screen just start session button with LightDM](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100010/no-password-asked-at-login-screen-just-start-session-button-with-lightdm/102222#102222)

Comment: Glad steeldriver helped you solve the problem. Please remember to accept your answer as the solution (by clicking check mark beside it) in 2 days.